# How to access another activity's XML from recyclerView adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-activity, android-recyclerview

This is my adapter's `onBindViewHolder` function:

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: InventoryHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.inventoryImageView.setImageResource(productList.get(position).image)
    holder.binding.productTextInventory.text = "Name: ${productList.get(position).name}"
    holder.binding.equipButton.setOnClickListener{

        if(productList.get(position).type == "Background"){
            //change main menu background photo.
            println("Background")
        }
        if(productList.get(position).type == "Character"){
            //change game character.
            println("Character")

        }


    }
    holder.binding.productTypeInventoryText.text = "Type: ${productList.get(position).type}"
}
```

As you can see it's a basic game inventory system. I need to change `activity_main.xml`'s components when equipButton clicked. For example I need to change image source here:

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:onClick="incScore"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/simpson" />
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use an interface which creates a connection between your Adapter and your Activity. The Adapter will receive an instance of the implemented interface and will use it to pass the selected item to the Activity which actually implements the interface.

Comment: How can I do this? I'm a beginner. Can you give me an example?(what should that interface contain etc.) Or do you have any tutorial suggestions for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could add lambda expression function parameter in your adapter like this

```
class YourAdapter(private val productList:List<Product>,private val onClickEquip:(String) -> Unit)
```

in your onClickListener you could use the function like this

```
holder.binding.equipButton.setOnClickListener{

    if(productList.get(position).type == "Background"){
        //change main menu background photo.
        onClickEquip("Background")
        println("Background")
    }
    if(productList.get(position).type == "Character"){
        //change game character.
        onClickEquip("Character")
        println("Character")

    }
}
```

and in your activity when you create your adapter instance like this

```
val adapter = YourAdapter(yourProductList) { type ->
        when(type){
            "Character" -> //Change image
            "Background" -> //Change image
        }
}
```

Comment: This solution is good but there is a problem. When in recyclerView "activity" I need to initialize adapter like that: `playerInventoryAdapter = InventoryAdapter(productList)` But it needs another parameter : type->unit . Because we wanted in InventoryAdapter.

Comment: What should I give to that parameter?

Comment: Check my latest edit

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have an `Activity` which contains a view with `Adapter` and you want to change a view which is part of `Activity`'s UI from that same `Adapter`.
In order to do so you can create an `interface` which will be used to pass the data between both sides. Let's say your `interface` looks like this:

```
interface OnInventoryClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(type: ProductType)
}
```

And inside your `Adapter` you have a variable of type `OnIventoryClickListener` which the `Activity` will provide:

```
lateinit var clickListener: OnInventoryClickListener

fun setListener(listener: OnInventoryClickListener){
    clickListener = listener
}
// ... Inside your onBindViewHolder
holder.binding.equipButton.setOnClickListener{
    clickListener.onItemClick(productList.get(position).type)
}
// ...
```

And from your `Activity` just call:

```
// adapter is the instance of your adapter.
adapter.setListener(object: OnInventoryClickListener {
    override fun onItemClick(type: Int) {
        // Change whatever you want based on type
    }
})
```

And that should do the trick. I suggest you to learn more about `interfaces` and how you can use them.

Comment: Thank you, this should work. But now there is another problem. I have to give a parameter (productList) to my adapter. And that causes a problem when I try to create an instance of it.

Comment: Okay I solved this problem. But now there is another one: " lateinit property clickListener has not been initialized"  I've done the initialiazition in the functiton like that as you said :    `fun setListener(listener: OnInventoryClickListener) {
        clickListener = listener
    }`

Comment: You can set your listener as parameter in your Adapter's constructor if it's used right away. It's just an example of how you can use interface.